# How can i spawn Objects randomly in a given area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawning

So im building a small Bulletgell game, and im at the point where I want Enemys to spawn in at random Spawnpoints in a given area. I did that with help of the BoxCollider2D, everything works fine but I want them to spawn OUTSIDE the actuall Map so they need to walk in the Map and Screen where the Player is. I just can spawn them in the whole are of the BoxCollider. Is there a way to determine which area the SpawnScript can use ?

In the Picture the red marked area should be the area where the Enemy spawn randomly.

Thanks for the help:)[image]

Heres the code im using atm:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class box : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject spawnedPrefab;
public BoxCollider2D spawnArea;
Vector2 maxSpawnPos;

float lastSpawnTimeS = -1;
public float spawnDelayS = 5;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    spawnArea = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    spawnArea.enabled = false; 
    maxSpawnPos = new Vector2(spawnArea.size.x / 2, spawnArea.size.y / 2);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (lastSpawnTimeS < 0)
    {
        lastSpawnTimeS = Time.time;
        GameObject spawned = Instantiate(spawnedPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        spawned.transform.parent = transform;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-maxSpawnPos.x, maxSpawnPos.x), Random.Range(-maxSpawnPos.y, maxSpawnPos.y), 0);
        spawned.transform.localPosition = pos;
    }
    else if (lastSpawnTimeS >= 0 && Time.time - lastSpawnTimeS > spawnDelayS)
    {
        lastSpawnTimeS = -1;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If object tries to go outside spawn area it will reset it to zero. You can also place if condition if object placed at zero add some random position within area.

```
if (lastSpawnTimeS < 0)
{
    lastSpawnTimeS = Time.time;
    GameObject spawned = Instantiate(spawnedPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    spawned.transform.parent = transform;
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-maxSpawnPos.x, maxSpawnPos.x) % spawnArea.size.x, Random.Range(-maxSpawnPos.y, maxSpawnPos.y) % spawnArea.size.y, 0);
    spawned.transform.localPosition = pos;
}
else if (lastSpawnTimeS >= 0 && Time.time - lastSpawnTimeS > spawnDelayS)
{
    lastSpawnTimeS = -1;
}
```